# How can increase the font size of autocomplete data for a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I Increase the font size of custom autocomlete on a text box?

I retrieve some autocomplete data from the database, but it uses the font from the textbox. In this case, that font is `gujarati`, and the font makes the autocomplete text invisible. My code is below:

```
private void txt()
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection ff = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ff = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    string sql = "select distinct p_name from product_master";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ff.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["p_name"].ToString());
    }
    txtRxName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ff;
    txtRxName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    txtRxName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}
```

In the above sample, I want to make the text in my AutoCompleteCustomSource larger.

Comment: Probably not possible. See [C#.NET TextBox: Change Autocomplete Font](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7203381/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech I love it. winforms doesn't support changing the font size.

Comment: @HirenRaiyani another reason to forget winforms and use current technologies. you can achieve this in WPF with less than 1 line of XAML.

Comment: @HighCore WPF has its moments.  Not sure how you can write `less than 1 line of XAML` though.

Comment: @LarsTech `<SomeElement FontSize="20"/>`? - That would be 1 line, though :P