# set panel border thickness in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, border, formborderstyle, thickness

I have searching and the result cannot solve my case.
Actually I have a panel and I want the panel have thicker border than Windows given.
I need BorderStyle

```
BorderStyle.FixedSingle
```

thicker..
Thanks before

Comment: Use use the Paint() event to make it look as thick as you want.

Comment: This is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852829/i-want-to-make-a-panel-have-a-thick-border-can-i-set-this-somehow). However, the accepted answer here is the only one that worked for me. The other solutions clipped off the right and bottom borders.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to customize your own `Panel` with a little custom painting:

```
//Paint event handler for your Panel
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){ 
  if(panel1.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle){
     int thickness = 3;//it's up to you
     int halfThickness = thickness/2;
     using(Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black,thickness)){
       e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, new Rectangle(halfThickness,
                                                 halfThickness,
                                                 panel1.ClientSize.Width-thickness,
                                                 panel1.ClientSize.Height-thickness));
     }
  }
}
```

Here is the screen shot of panel with thickness of `30`:

[image: Screen shot of panel with border thickness of 30]

**NOTE**: The Size of `Rectangle` is calculated at the middle of the drawing line, suppose you draw line with thickness of `4`, there will be an offset of 2 outside and 2 inside.

I didn't test the case given by Mr `Hans`, to fix it simply handle the event `SizeChanged` for your `panel1` like this:

```
private void panel1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

You can also setting `ResizeRedraw = true` using `Reflection` without having to handle the `SizeChanged` event as above like this:

```
typeof(Control).GetProperty("ResizeRedraw", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
               .SetValue(panel1, true, null);
```

You may see a little flicker when resizing, just add this code to enable doubleBuffered for your panel1:

```
typeof(Panel).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                          BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
             .SetValue(panel1,true,null);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what actually I want :D

Comment: Dock the panel on the right+bottom and resize the form to see it go wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for pointing it out, looks like when customizing control we always have to add code handling `resizing`.

Comment: @KingKing one more to my collection.

Comment: @HighCore what have you been collecting? Don't tell me that you have been collecting `winforms sample code` to learn it better :)))

Comment: @KingKing I've been collecting samples that show how things that can be achieved with a single line of XAML require all sorts of horrible hacks in crappy dinosaur winforms =). This would be `<Border BorderThickness="30"/>`, y'know

Comment: @KingKing I've also discovered recently that [winforms doesn't support changing the Font Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118165/how-can-increase-the-font-size-of-autocomplete-data-for-a-textbox). I'm in awe.

Answer (score 4):

To create a panel with border I place a panel in a panel. The "border panel" has the background color of the wanted border color and a padding, while the `padding` size is the wanted border `thickness`.

The advantage of this solution is that there is no flickering and no problems with resize.

[image]

[image]

This can be very simple be created in the designer or in code behind.

Code behind:

```
Panel panel_Border = new Panel();
Panel panel_Embedded = new Panel();

panel_Border.BackColor = Color.Green;
panel_Border.Controls.Add(panel_Embedded);
// this is the border thickness
panel_Border.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6);
panel_Border.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
        
panel_Embedded.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
panel_Embedded.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new, slightly larger panel and set the background colour to Black (or whatever).  Place the original panel INSIDE the larger panel.