# How do I set the margin for my panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a windows form that will programatically add a panel to another panel. I'm trying to customize the various properties of the new panel, such as color, and size, which works. However when I try to modify the margin, nothing works. I cannot find the `Thickness` struct either, since it's not a WPF app, it's a Windows Forms Application. Here is my code:

```
    private void buttonAddExercise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.BackColor = Color.White;
        panel.Size = new Size(200, 300);

        panel.Margin = new Padding(20);


        listOfExercisePanels.Add(panel);
        panelNewWorkout.Controls.Add(panel);
    }
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003772/setting-margin-properties-in-code

Comment: i tried that article and didnt work, as i said, i cant find the thickness object

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to find the thickness object? You create a [Thickness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx) object (actually a struct) with the appropriate settings & then assign that to the Margin as shown in the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Margin Properties in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003772/setting-margin-properties-in-code)

Comment: When I type `Thickness`, it's underlined with red...

Comment: I found out that `Thickness` exists in WPF Apps, but not in Windows Forms Application. I dont know what to do.

Comment: @MacMan That's not a duplicate, the linked question is about WPF, but this one is on WinForms. Answer to both are completely unrelated.

Comment: As you found out, Thickness is in WPF. Here's your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163809/set-panel-border-thickness-in-c-sharp-winform

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**

To use `Thickness` you need to create/change your project .NET framework platform 
version to `.NET Framework 4.5`. because this method available only in version 4.5

**Secondly**

You must add `Dock`Style to `Fill` for *Child* components as:

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.BackColor = Color.White;
        panel.Size = new Size(200, 200);

        Label lb = new Label() { Text = "Hello" };

        panel.Padding = new Padding(10);
        lb.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

        panel.Controls.Add(lb);

        this.Controls.Add(panel);
```

**Thirdly**

If you want to change Margin of the panel, you can put it into another parent panel

Answer (score -1):

Add a reference to "PresentationFramework.dll",

and a using statement for:

```
using System.Windows;
```

PresentationFramework is not included as a reference by default.

Comment: That's WPF...question says WinForms.

Comment: Luckily you can add that assembly to a WinForms app regardless hey.

Comment: Can does not equal should.

Comment: :D luckily this is solved in 4.5 so its a non issue.
But adding a reference to PresentationFramework is hardly wrong.